# GraphQL nested query returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-tools

When attempting to run the following query I get this error: "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.first_name.". I am not expecting a null result.

```
Query:
{
  site(site_reference: 123456789) {
    site_name
    site_managers {
      _id
      first_name
    }
  }
}
```

What I expect to see is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "site_name": "Test Site",
      "site_managers": [
        {
          "_id": "5bbcd55ff7bd643be4d490fa",
          "first_name": "Claire"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5b9fa2e1f66fb32164f4d547",
          "first_name": "John"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My MongoDB stores the _id in an array which it is able to return, however anything else from my user type returns null.

User Schema:

```
type User {
    _id: String!,
    first_name: String!,
    last_name: String!,
    role_id: Int!
    email: String!,
    password: String,
    created_date: String!,
    updated_date: String!,
    last_login_date: String,
    reset_password_token: String
  }
  type Query {
    user(_id: String!): User!
    users(role_id: Int): [User!]!
  }
```

User Resolver:

```
  Query: {
    user: (parent, args) => User.findById(args._id),
    users: (parent, args) => {
      if (args.role_id) {
        return User.find({ role_id: args.role_id })
      }
      return User.find({})
    },
  },
```

Site Schema:

```
  type Site {
    site_name: String!,
    use_policy: String!,
    redirect_url: String!,
    intro_text: String!,
    logo: String!,
    address_line_1: String!,
    address_line_2: String,
    address_city: String!,
    address_county: String!,
    address_postcode: String!,
    phone: String!,
    site_reference: Int!,
    site_managers: [User],
    business_id: String!,
    connect_duration: Int!,
    created_date: String!,
    updated_date: String!,
  }

  type Query {
    site(site_reference: Int!): Site!
    sites(business_id: Int!): [Site!]!
  }
```

Site Resolver:

```
  Query: {
    site: (parent, args) =>
      Site.findOne({ site_reference: args.site_reference }),
    sites: (parent, args) => Site.find({ business_id: args.business_id }),
  },
```

I imagine I need to do more in my resolver for the site query but I am unsure of what exactly. I have already tried using mongoose.populate but to no avail, the furthest I got was returning an empty array with the populate method.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Edit:
Here's my mongoose schemas

User Schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: { type: String, required: true },
  last_name: { type: String, required: true },
  role_id: { type: Number, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String },
  created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
  updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
  last_login_date: { type: Date },
  reset_password_token: { type: String },
})
```

Site Schema:

```
const SiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  site_name: { type: String, required: true },
  use_policy: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: config.defaultUsePolicy,
  },
  redirect_url: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: config.defaultRedirect,
  },
  intro_text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: config.defaultIntroText,
  },
  logo: { type: String, required: true, default: config.defaultLogo },
  address_line_1: { type: String, required: true },
  address_line_2: String,
  address_city: { type: String, required: true },
  address_county: { type: String, required: true },
  address_postcode: { type: String, required: true },
  phone: { type: String, required: true },
  site_reference: { type: String, required: true },
  site_managers: {type:[mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], required: true}
  business_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  connect_duration: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
  updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
})
```

Comment: Hi, it would be useful to see the relevant mongoose schemas as well. Can you update your question?

Comment: No problem I've added them to the question 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MongoDB and mongoose, you will want to use `populate` to join your collections. In order to do so, in your schema, the field you're populating needs to not only have a type, but also a `ref` property that tells mongoose which Model to use to populate the field, for example:

```
// Note the actual ref should be whatever name you passed to mongoose.model
site_managers: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
```

Now, use `populate` inside your resolver:

```
site: (parent, { site_reference }) => {
  return Site.findOne({ site_reference }).populate('site_managers').exec()
}
```

See the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for more detailed examples.

Comment: Thank you so much! Where I messed up previously trying to use populate was I added the ref to the mongoose schema but outside of the array. e.g. site_managers: { type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'User' }, using this code worked perfectly!